# Is it possible to use VI or VIM keymap in NetBeans?

Tags: vim, netbeans, vi, jvi

Vim is my favorite tool for programming in OSX, but my team mate all use NetBeans. Some of them use Eclipse Keymap. Any suggestion plug-in to enable VI command in NetBeans 6.5?

#### Related:

> [Does any IDE have a vi keybindings option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294613/does-any-ide-have-a-vi-keybindings-options)

Comment: Funny, I was looking for the contrary. NetBeans keymap in VIM :D

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check [jVi](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/), a Vi emulator for NetBeans.

I've also found [ViEx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/viex/), the project seems to be pretty active...

Comment: I'm using jVi and love it. Works great on NetBeans 6.5

Answer (score 5):

[jVi](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/) can be installed using the NetBeans plugin manager; from NB do

```
Menu>Tools>Plugins
```

Select the tab "Available Plugins", in search enter "jvi". First install "jVi for NB-xx Update Center", then you can install jVi.

Comment: Cannot be in netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: [jVi](http://jvi.sourceforge.net) works in every NetBeans release, AFAIK, since before NB-7.0 and to NB-11.x. What problem are you having @typelogic ?

Comment: I am only able to install the `jvi` plugin manager. Next I refreshed, and i did not see any `jvi` under the `Editors` category.

Comment: You can download a zip and manually install. Also can check NB messages.log for errors. Can email to jvi support, see website.