# Vim plugin for Netbeans IDE

Tags: vim, netbeans, ide, vim-plugin

I have found a couple of Vim plugin for Eclipse, but some computers have performance issues with Eclipse.

So, what I want to know if there is any plugin for the Netbeans IDE, which runs smoother on weaker computers.

If it matters, I'm interested in support for Java, Python and C++. (any answer regarding to one of them in welcomed) .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found these, apparently they even have some features my eclipse plugin doesn't:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/viex/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvi/

From: [Is it possible to use VI or VIM keymap in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483962/is-it-possible-to-use-vi-or-vim-keymap-in-netbeans?rq=1)

Answer (score 12):

I got jVi for my NetBeans 8.1 and 8.0.2 on Mac OS this way:

1. Download nbvi-1.5.3.zip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvi/.
2. Unzip it somewhere.
3. Tools > Plugins > Downloaded
4. Click "Add Plugins..." button.
5. Navigate to the folder where those *.nbm reside and select all of them.
6. Install the *.nbm files and restart.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in the traditional way, but this worked on NetBeans 8.1. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! +1. Worked on Netbeans 8.0.2 on Mac OS :)

Comment: i fiddled with other solutions for the Mac for hours, you can get your plugin state irreversibly messed up. This solution is much cleaner. You can't double-click the zip file in certain new MacOS configurations, you have to start a terminal window and manually unzip the file. Then add all the .nbm files that appear in the resulting folder. Then everything works.

Comment: It works but I was unable to show line numbers in Netbeans 8.2 after removing the plugin. I had to remove the folder ~/ .netbeans/8.2/config/Editors folder to show the numbers again

Comment: If I were you, I would not care about that because the plugin always shows the cursor position in the lower right corner in line:column format. However, you can turn on the numbers this way: NetBeans -> Preferences -> jVi Config -> General then check 'number' 'nu'.

Answer (score 11):

Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins -> Search: `vi`

The plugin is called "jVi for NB". If you search for `vim`, the results will be empty.

The truth *is* that it's really *that* easy to find and install a vi[m] emulator for NetBeans. You don't even have to type the whole three letters.

[image]

Comment: In other words -- there aren't any?

Comment: If you search for "vim", nothing comes up.

Comment: It's a valid question, vim style editing is expected in all editors.. I still can't believe there's nothing for netbeans..

Comment: @breno-salgado: it is not a valid question to ask to random people on the internet because it is freaking easy to find the answer yourself. That question is almost as dumb as "what is the shortcut for cut?".

Comment: So why then was your answer wrong? See mine. This is a QA site, it's precisely about asking stuff to random people on the internet, it's also a resource for people looking for these answers(how I got here), I saw yours and almost thought of it as true and went to sleep so it tells me that if you wanted this question answered, you'd also not be able to find the answer yourself easy like this, so it's not dumb plus the answer is misleading and useless.

Comment: @BrenoSalgado, yes it's super dumb and super lazy to ask people to do something that you can do yourself. Especially something as simple and trivial as looking for a vim plugin for NetBeans. Asking questions is perfectly fine as long as you do a little bit of work on your side.

Comment: Your answer is wrong because it misleads the reader that there are no such plugins while there are.

Comment: I wasted time following this advice thinking I could install a vim plugin this way. This search does not result in any plugins.

Comment: @MidoriKid, you are blind.

Comment: Nonsense. Typing in `vi` results in 85 plugins, most of which are irrelevant. Do you expect the user to plough through all of them or what. That's definitely not "freaking easy". Not to mention your quite arrogant tone...

Comment: Note that adding this "jVi for NB 7.0 update center" did not work for me. It's possible that version 8 of NetBeans broke its behavior. I had to download the plugin manually from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvi/, and go to Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded panel, and then click on "Add Plugins..." to add them from my disk manually.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 10):

I got vim editing mode on NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 on Windows 10 by doing the following:

1. Tools > Plugins > Check for Updates
2. Click Available Plugins Tab
3. Search "jVI"
4. Install "jVi for NB-7.0 Update Center"
5. Click available plugins tab
6. Click "Check for Newest"
7. Search "jVI"
8. Install jVI, and restart NetBeans
9. hjlkhjlhlkjhlkjhkjlh

Comment: "Check for Newest" +1