# What modal editors are available aside from vi/vim?

Tags: vim, editor, vi

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410/why-are-there-so-few-modal-editors-that-arent-vi) asked why there are so few non-vi modal editors. A few of the comments in that question mentioned other modal editors in passing, but I think that it would be useful to develop a more comprehensive list. Searching for this information on Google is difficult, as vim-related information tends to drown out everything else.

A few items to get things rolling:

- Divascheme ([From the previously mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410/why-are-there-so-few-modal-editors-that-arent-vi))
- Ed ([According to this](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/cs211_moreno_2007/notes/unix-editors-W2007.pdf))

Comment: Change title to "vi and clones" to clarify that nvi, elvis, etc. don't answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been many Non-vi modal editors over the years.  Many of them tied to a single operating system.

WordStar, edlin, and ISPF come to mind.  Also EDIT from the HDOS system.  There are probably at least a dozen others named EDIT or it's variants.

Comment: ISPF is not modal! There is an input field for global commands, input fields by each line for line commands, and the WYSWYG update of the screen is mostly handled by the 3270 terminla rather than the editor. At no time do switch modes -- which is waht defines a modal editor.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but AFAIK Emacs has a plugin to emulate vi's modal editing.

Comment: You mean Viper (http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/viper.html), the spiritual inverse of Vimacs (http://www.algorithm.com.au/code/vimacs/).  Yes, some people are crazy enough to use both.  :-)

Comment: There's also [evil mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil).

Answer (score -2):

Elvis is one of these editors.
Also, nvi could count as one.

Comment: Both of those are vi clones, so they don't really count.